# Creating multiple screens in a for loop to run parellel programs and sending commands to each

Tags: linux, command-line, script, gnu-screen

Before flagging this questions as redundant, i have read and tried every answer to similar questions with no success

I have this loop where it traverses a directory structure, and runs a program (which takes minutes to finish) in each subdirectory in a separate screen. I don't want to see the output of the screens and want them all to execute the program in the background in parallel. So far I have

```
for ((i = 1; i <= noLines; i++))
do
# code to change path to point to next executable goes here

screen -d -m -S results_$i -X stuff $(./runSimulator.sh 1 5 results) $'\012'    

done
```

What happens is that the code executes in the current active screen and the code is serialized on the same screen. I need to run multiple versions at the same time in different screens. Could you help please?

I tried all these and it did not work (errors(no socket found) / nothing happened or same as above)

1. screen -d -m ./runSimulator.sh 1 5 results $'\012'
2. screen -d -m -S results_$i -X screen $(./runSimulator.sh 1 5 results) $'\012'
3. screen -d -m -S results_$i 
   screen -S results_$i -X stuff $(./runSimulator.sh 1 5 results) $'\012'

please help

Comment: What is the reason you go for `screen`instead of simple background jobs with stdout/stderr redirection?

Comment: i am connecting to a remote server and running those through ssh. thus i use screen

Comment: Why not run with backgrounded with redirected in/out, which completes immediately, then use your redirected IOs (e.g. to/from FIFOs) to interact with the instances? Do you use anything fancy in the i/o (such as ncurses), that would create problems?

Comment: Actually I did as you told me and it worked beautifuly. Thanks man. I am a novice in linux and scripting.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Comment: The syntax for `tmux` is much simpler and it's the same for the config file and command line, which is just one of the reasons it's much better than `screen`.

Comment: @paradroid, can you answer your own question with the solution that you found?

Comment: @T.BrianJones No, as this is not something that I have attempted to do or want to do (I didn't make any question), but I am sure it will be much easier to achieve in `tmux` for the reasons I mentioned.  Whenever I have a problem regarding tmux, I got to #tmux on Freenode and get it solved quickly, especially if 'nicm' (the main developer) is there.